# SQL Server Case update not allowing greater than

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to update a table based with a status, based on a date base condition, however SSMS is saying the > is incorrect syntax?

```
UPDATE [Inbound]
SET [Rev Status] = CASE [Rev Status]
WHEN (CONVERT (Date, GETDATE())) > [Rev Date]  THEN 'Late'
ELSE 'On Time'
END;
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your `CASE` syntax is wrong. You should be using the `Searched CASE expression` syntax. Refer to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for the correct syntax

Comment: What Squirrel means is you are mistakenly mixing the two `CASE` syntaxes. Simply remove `[Rev Status]` from `CASE [Rev Status]` and you are done. A mere typo in my opinion. But next time please show the complete error message.

Answer (score 2):

The `CASE` statement syntax is wrong here, if I am correct, the query would be like this :

```
UPDATE [Inbound]
    SET [Rev Status] = CASE WHEN (CONVERT (Date, GETDATE())) > [Rev Date]  
    THEN 'Late' ELSE 'On Time'
    END;
```

See detail about `CASE` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)